# Socket Programing using Code Blocks

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying Socket programming using code blocks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

int main()
{
    int sock;

    sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock == -1)
    {
        printf("\n Socket not created %d\n", sock);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The line to create socket gives me -1. What am I missing any help?

Comment: as a general suggestion, use `perror` because it will also give you the appropriate error message

Comment: What's that constant `0` for the protocol? Shouldn't it be one of the `IPPROTO_` constants?

Comment: `IPPROTO_TCP`, for instance

Comment: [IPv6 Socket Program Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906736/ipv6-socket-program-problem)

Comment: "Normally only a single protocol exists to support a particular  socket type within a given protocol family, in which case protocol can be specified as 0." Not sure if win32 holds the same opinion, though.

Comment: Q. What does 'using code blocks' have to do with it? A. Nothing.

Comment: @EJP [Xcode tag.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode) - Some people can't even imagine iOS development without Xcode, and they want to "integrate Facebook into Xcode", "pop up a window in Xcode", and "learn Xcode programming". No matter I've been writing iOS apps on Linux (with `nano` and `make`) since 2010...

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't see anything even slightly Xcode-ish about this code, or anything even slightly out of the usual.

Comment: @EJP I didn't say this code was Xcode-ish. I was just citing this as a similarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call [`WSAStartup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to initiate use of the Winsock DLL by a process.

Also, call [`WSACleanUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function at the end.

From the link [WSAStartup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

*The **`WSAStartup`** function **must be the first Windows Sockets function called** by an 
application or DLL. It allows an application or DLL to specify the version of Windows
Sockets required and retrieve details of the specific Windows Sockets implementation.
The application or DLL can only issue further Windows Sockets functions after 
successfully calling `WSAStartup`.*

A good example is also given in the above link.

Also:

***An application must call the `WSACleanup` function** for every successful time the `WSAStartup`
 function is called. This means, for example, that if an application calls `WSAStartup` 
three times, it must call `WSACleanup` three times. The first two calls to `WSACleanup` do
 nothing except decrement an internal counter; the final `WSACleanup` call for the task 
does all necessary resource deallocation for the task.*

Comment: Thanks, perfect one! Not sure how I missed it.