# is there a way to reuse the socket addersses in C++/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have a while loop for retrying to connect to  a device.
problem is, every time it does retry it is using the same socket descriptor(closing and opening again), is this safe?

```
while(retry)
  create socket
  read(use socket created before)
  if read fails
     close socket and retry
```

i want a new socket fd to connect with the server and read again. Is reusing the same one safe in case read has failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually `close` the socket then I would suggest to create a new socket since the `fd` used for to describe the socket is now invalid so your reuse of the same file descriptor could cause errors.

Normally though it's better to close the old and create a new one.

Comment: I am closing the socket and creating the new one, but since i closed say socket fd 'x', when i try to create a new one immediately after that, it gives me 'x' as new socket fd.

Comment: @user1035818 This is absolutely fine.  The old `fd` and all the stuff associated with it has been released back to the OS, so even if the number you get is the same the resources are new.

Comment: @user1035818 Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160347/close-vs-shutdown-socket

Comment: You can't reuse a (connection based) socket once you've called `shutdown` on it.

Comment: @Hasturkun Retested and removed that suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

since you called bind or connect on the socket, you can't change the address.
you must close the socket and create the new one.