# Unexpected TCP RST packet

Tags: tcp

We are facing random RST packet problem in our environments, which causes some unexpected behaviors, following image is snapshot of the tcp data generated by wireshark, which shows the problem:

1. Client (117.136.2.181) successfully sets up the connection with the server (192.168.40.16)
2. Client sends some data to the server, as well the KEEP_ALIVE signal.
3. Server receives the data, process it and sends the result back to client.
4. Server close the socket.
5. Server does not receive the ACK signal from client, so it re-transmits the result data as well as the FIN signal, this is automatically done by TCP protocol. However, server still does not receive the ACK signal from client.
6. Server sends a RST signal to client so connection is closed.

[image: TCP data packet]

After some analysis, we think some network problem happens after step 3, so all the result data and FIN signal sent from server are not ack'd by client, but we are very confused about the RST signal sent from the server. Based on our understanding, a RST signal is sent if a half-closed socket receives some data, or if there is data in the receive queue when closes a socket. But both these seem not be the root cause of our case.

Can some one help to elaborate why this is happening?

Comment: Why are we seeing keep alives immediately after data? It looks like someone has horribly broken the TCP stack on the end sending the keep alives.

Comment: I'll have to dig into the code to find out that, can this cause the RST happens?

Comment: It definitely seems to be the instigating event.

Comment: Can you please explain more about this? Besides, we see other unexpected RST without KEEP_ALIVE~

Comment: Are these some custom/experimental TCP stacks or standard?

Comment: I believe this is the standard tcp stack~

Answer (score 0):

`RST` usually happens when `close` is called on the socket without `shutdown`, or after a `shutdown` while the other party is still trying to send data (still has not replied with an `FIN`).

Some programming languages have a `socket.close(timeout)` for [example .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.close), that calls `shutdown` then `close` after `timeout` has passed.

So the client have up to `timeout` to finish sending and closing the connection with `FIN`, if it fails to do so, the connection will be forcibly closed by `RST`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23483487/1438522 for a more thorough explanation about difference between `close` and `shutdown`.