# How to send FIN Flag to host without closing socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, posix

I've written a C code which creates a socket and it works fine so far.
In the RFC for TCP i found out that it is possible to send a FIN flag to tell the other host that i want to quit or conversation. The FIN flag does not mean that the other host isn't able to send more data. So in a perfect world i would send the FIN Flag and the other host knows that i dont want to talk anymore he sends the rest of data and shuts down after that.
But how can i send the FIN???
The close() function does that for me or better set the linux kernel does when he puts away the resource.
But putting away the resource means that i cant use the recv() function anymore because the file descriptor was put away by the kernel when i called the close() function.
So how is it possible to read the rest of data that the other host may wants to send after my FIN flag.
I bet there is a clean solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to shutdown your write-side of the socket with [`shutdown(s, SHUT_WR)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html).

> The `shutdown()` call causes all or part of a full-duplex connection on
>          the socket associated with sockfd to be shut down.  If how is
>          `SHUT_RD`, further receptions will be disallowed.  If how is `SHUT_WR`,
>          further transmissions will be disallowed.  If how is `SHUT_RDWR`,
>          further receptions and transmissions will be disallowed.

See also:

- [close vs shutdown socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4160347/119527)