# Difference between Socket::close() and StreamSocket::shutdown()

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, poco-libraries

When using Poco's `StreamSocket` class and you want to close the socket connection, it is unclear from both the Poco documentation and the function implementations whether `Socket::close()` or `StreamSocket::shutdown()` would be the most appropriate function to call. On platforms where these appear to forward through to POSIX functions, the man page for `shutdown()` states that sending/receiving will be stopped, but says nothing about the connection itself. Would I be safe in assuming that `close()` is essentially going to be a superset of what `shutdown()` does and hence `close()` is the more appropriate one to call? If so, is there an example scenario where `shutdown()` would be the more appropriate call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shutdown` function shuts down either the sending side of the connection, the receiving side of the connection, or both. The `close` function just closes the socket and doesn't necessarily have any effect on the connection. However, if the connection has no references (because you `close`d the last one), then the operating system will shut down the connection.

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer since it is the most technically correct. The answer by @865719 contains links which provide considerably more detail and useful background which complements David's answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [POCO's introductory slides on Network Programming](http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf):

> POCO sockets are a very thin layer on top of BSD sockets
>
> -- Slide #7

So POCO sockets adopt BSD socket's semantics for `close()` and `shutdown()`.

As mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4160356/865719) (which refers to [Beej's guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#closedown)):

<s>`close()` will prevent reads/writes on the remote socket</s> whereas `shutdown()` gives you more control on which end is to be cut off. (which explains the presence of [`StreamSocket::shutdownSend()`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.StreamSocket.html#24797) and [`StreamSocket::shutdownReceive()`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.StreamSocket.html#24796) alongside [`StreamSocket::shutdown()`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.StreamSocket.html#24798))

**EDIT**: make sure to check out [David Schwartz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075482/difference-between-socketclose-and-streamsocketshutdown#comment53970238_33076469) about the accuracy of Beej's guide concerning the actual effects of `close()`.

Comment: The `close` function doesn't necessarily prevent reads or writes like `shutdown` does.

Comment: I was quoting [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#closedown): "`close(sockfd);`: This will prevent any more reads and writes to the socket. Anyone attempting to read or write the socket on the remote end will receive an error."

Comment: Yes, but you said "on both ends of the socket", implying that it has an effect on the connection. Now you say the "remote socket", which it also doesn't necessarily have any effect on.

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed it :)

Comment: Beej is wrong. You can see that he's wrong by `dup`ing the socket, then `close`ing it, then trying to `write` on the remote end. It will work just fine.

Comment: Interesting, I'll make sure to check it out later. Thanks for the comment.