# When/why to use s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, python-sockets

I have just started learning python network programming. I was reading Foundations of Python Network Programming and could not understand the use of s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR) where s is a socket object.
Here is the code(where sys.argv[2] is the number of bytes user wants to send, which is rounded off to a multiple of 16) in which it is used:

```
import socket, sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 1060

if sys.argv[1:] == ['server']:
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        print 'Listening at', s.getsockname()
        sc, sockname = s.accept()
        print 'Processing up to 1024 bytes at a time from', sockname
        n = 0
        while True:
            message = sc.recv(1024)
            if not message:
                break
            sc.sendall(message.upper())  # send it back uppercase
            n += len(message)
            print '\r%d bytes processed so far' % (n,),
            sys.stdout.flush()
        print
        sc.close()
        print 'Completed processing'

elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1] == 'client' and sys.argv[2].isdigit():

    bytes = (int(sys.argv[2]) + 15) // 16 * 16  # round up to // 16
    message = 'capitalize this!'  # 16-byte message to repeat over and over

    print 'Sending', bytes, 'bytes of data, in chunks of 16 bytes'
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))

    sent = 0
    while sent < bytes:
        s.sendall(message)
        sent += len(message)
        print '\r%d bytes sent' % (sent,),
        sys.stdout.flush()

    print
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

    print 'Receiving all the data the server sends back'

    received = 0
    while True:
        data = s.recv(42)
        if not received:
            print 'The first data received says', repr(data)
        received += len(data)
        if not data:
            break
        print '\r%d bytes received' % (received,),

    s.close()

else:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'usage: tcp_deadlock.py server | client <bytes>'
```

And this is the explanation that the author provides which I am finding hard to understand:

> Second, you will see that the client makes a shutdown() call on the socket after it finishes sending its transmission. This solves an important problem: if the server is going to read forever until it sees end-of-file, then how will the client avoid having to do a full close() on the socket and thus forbid itself from doing the many recv() calls that it still needs to make to receive the server’s response? The solution is to “half-close” the socket—that is, to permanently shut down communication in one direction but without destroying the socket itself—so that the server can no longer read any data, but can still send any remaining reply back in the other direction, which will still be open.

My understanding of what it will do is that it will prevent the client application from further sending the data and thus will also prevent the server side from further attempting to read any data.

What I cant understand is that why is it used in this program and in what situations should I consider using it in my programs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [close vs shutdown socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160347/close-vs-shutdown-socket)

Comment: I cant understand why is it used. I have an idea about what it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My understanding of what it will do is that it will prevent the client
>   application from further sending the data and thus will also prevent
>   the server side from further attempting to read any data.

Your understanding is correct.

> What I cant understand is that why is it used in this program …

As your own statement suggests, without the client's `s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)` the server would not quit waiting for data, but instead stick in its `sc.recv(1024)` forever, because there would be no connection termination request sent to the server.
Since the server then would never get to its `sc.close()`, the client on his part also would not quit waiting for data, but instead stick in its `s.recv(42)` forever, because there would be no connection termination request sent from the server.
Reading [this answer to "close vs shutdown socket?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23483487/2413201) might also be enlightening.

Answer (score -1):

The explanation is half-baked, it applies *only* to this specific code and overall I would vote with all-fours that this is bad practice.

Now to understand why is it so, you need to look at a server code. This server works by blocking execution until it receives 1024 bytes. Upon reception it processes the data (makes it upper-case) and sends it back. Now the problem is with hardcoded value of 1024. What if your string is shorter than 1024 bytes?

To resolve this you need to tell the server that - hey there is no more data coming your way, so return from `message = sc.recv(1024)` and you do this by shutting down the socket in one direction.

You do not want to fully close the socket, because then the server would not be able to send you the reply.

Comment: It is just a example code which is not going to be used anywhere. The server will not block execution until it receives 1024 bytes, instead sc.recv(1024) would return the number of bytes it received even if they are less than 1024(as long as they are greater than 0).

Comment: recv will block until it gets something. You are not guaranteed that it will get the full string you are sending. It can return after receiving first character only

Comment: Yes, I wrote the same thing above.