# Is SO_REUSEADDR socket options useful on the client-side?

Tags: linux, sockets

I came across the sentence in one java client library:

`socket.setReuseAddress(true);`

Thought this is used to improve performance, 
since the `SO_REUSEADDR` option can indicate that socket can forcibly
use the TIME_WAIT port even if it belongs to the other socket.

But Also I found that this option is mostly used in the server-side,
to enable the server restarting quickly, not waiting the TIME_WAIT socket to close.

My question is that Is this option useful for the client-side, 
like this client library? Will this do harmful to the other socket, like some attack?

Thanks a lot!

-Dimi

Comment: It is not *typically* used on the client side, but there is one case where it is - TCP hole punching through a NAT, which requires multiple sockets to be bound to the same local IP/Port at the same time, so they have to use `SO_REUSEADDR`/`SO_REUSEPORT`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was wondering if there have been any experience that shows it helped a lot on the (client) performance by setting this option ?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by "client". You also mention "client library", which has nothing to do with it.

This is often misunderstood, `SO_REUSEADDR` is to be able to reuse a socket in `TIME_WAIT`, and `TIME_WAIT` only happens on one side of the TCP connection, **the one that initiates the termination sequence** i.e. sends the first `FIN` packet i.e. calls `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` first or calls `close` first, although the latter is unclear/may depend on other things such as connection state or platform, reasons why you [should not call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160347/close-vs-shutdown-socket) `close` before first calling `shutdown(SHUT_WR)`. [This article](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html) is a very informative as well as the two referenced at the end of the article. It makes clear that `TIME_WAIT` may occur on the listening (server) side as well as client side, and recommends actually having clients always initiate termination ("active close") so that the server doesn't accumulate sockets in `TIME_WAIT`, where that would be more of a problem.