# In tcl, how to close a socket/channel created by dp_MakeRPCClient from forked child without closing it in the parent

Tags: linux, sockets, tcl

I'm communicating between two processes in tcl using Tcl-DP.
I create a server using `dp_MakeRPCServer` on one processs and a client on the other process using `dp_MakeRPCClient`.
When the client is created it connect to the server and a new socket is created between both processes.

First process

```
dp_MakeRPCServer 50000
file channel
> stdin stdout stderr tcp0
```

Second process

```
dp_MakeRPCClient <host> 50000
file channel
> stdin stdout stderr tcp0
```

First process

```
file channel
> stdin tcp2 stdout stderr tcp0
```

We can see that `tcp2` on the first process is the socket.
Now I'm doing fork and the channels are cloned into the child.

child process (forked from first process)

```
file channel
stdin tcp2 stdout stderr tcp0
```

I want to close `tcp2` (the socket) on the child without closing the socket between first and second processes.

`close tcp2` will just close the socket, in the child, in the first process and in the second process.

I will also accept any other suggestion to do it which consider:

- At any time other processes may try to connect to the server of the first process. I don't want the child process to receive those calls.
- At any time the second process may start sending messages to the first process. Again, I don't want the child process to receive those messages.

I should mention that I'm using TclDp 4.0 and tcl 8.4.

Comment: I'd expect this to work, based on everything (see my answer). Are you sure you're not just talking to the subprocess instead of the parent? That's the sort of silly error I'd make…

Comment: I read your answer and it seems to give an answer to my problem except one little problem. It doesn't work :-). 
I made sure I indeed close tcp2 on the child.
Is there anyway to snip the process and see which system call is actually called?

Answer (score 0):

The following requires you to read [the socket FAQ](http://web.deu.edu.tr/doc/soket/#faq12) first, but here's the key bit:

> Generally the difference between `close()` and `shutdown()` is: `close()` closes the socket id for the process but the connection is still opened if another process shares this socket id. The connection stays opened both for read and write, and sometimes this is very important. `shutdown()` breaks the connection for all processes sharing the socket id. Those who try to read will detect `EOF`, and those who try to write will reseive `SIGPIPE`, possibly delayed while the kernel socket buffer will be filled. Additionally, `shutdown()` has a second argument which denotes how to close the connection: 0 means to disable further reading, 1 to disable writing and 2 disables both.

On Unix, the Tcl `close` command on a socket will map to the `close()` system call on the socket with the standard socket implementation unless you ask for a specific direction to be closed (a Tcl 8.6 feature) in which case the `shutdown()` system call will be used. This means that with a standard socket, if opened in a parent process prior to a fork, the parent should `close` the socket after forking. (It's not usually a good idea to have two processes reading from the same TCP socket at once; things get very confused.)

*However,* TclDP uses its own implementation of socket channels which [only supports closing via the `close()` system call](http://tcldp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tcldp/tcldp/unix/dpSock.c?revision=1.3&view=markup) on Unix. (I've not checked on Windows; I don't know the system API very well there.)

That said, I'd expect the `close tcp2` in the child process to work provided the parent still has the socket open. In this respect, Tcl really does just expose the capabilities of the operating system. It does not do any special things to make closes in children affect parents.

### See Also

- [close vs shutdown socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160347/close-vs-shutdown-socket)